# My navigation in childtheme is not responsive after update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've build a child theme on top of the build in theme twenty-seven-teen. After an update of the main theme my top menu is only showing in mobile or tablet mode. Everything else is working fine.

Could you please advise me on where to look for the problem? I have been comparing the files in my child to those in the main theme, but I can't find the problem.

Here is my header code, even thou I'm not sure if the issue lies here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php wp_body_open(); ?>

<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="navigation-top">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .wrap -->
            </div><!-- .navigation-top -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <?php

    /*
     * If a regular post or page, and not the front page, show the featured image.
     * Using get_queried_object_id() here since the $post global may not be set before a call to the_post().
     */
    if ( ( is_single() ||  is_page() )  && has_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id() ) ) :
        echo '<div class="single-featured-image-header">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id(), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );
        echo '</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->';
    endif;
    ?>

    
            <div class="naeste_koncert" style="background-color: #003559; color: #fff">NÆSTE KONCERT: 
    
    <?php 
   // the query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
   )); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>


</div>

    <div class="site-content-contain">
        <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Here is the CSS for the child theme:

```
/*
Theme Name:     twenty_seventeen_child
Description:    Chield theme for lisbjergbigband.dk
Author:         admin
Template:       twentyseventeen

(optional values you can add: Theme URI, Author URI, Version, License, License URI, Tags, Text Domain)
*/
@import url("../twentyseventeen/style.css");

.navigation-top {

    background: #003559 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #003559 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #003559 !important;
    color: #fff !important;

}

.navigation-top .site-navigation-fixed .menu {
    background-color: #003559;
}

.naeste_koncert {
    padding:29px;
}
.site-footer{
    background-color:#003559;
    color:#fff;
}

.navigation-top {
    background: #003559 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #003559 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #003559 !important;
}
.navigation-top a {
    /*color: #222;*/
    color: #fff !important;
}   
.navigation-top .current_page_item > a {
    /*color: #767676;*/
    color: hsl( 250, 50%, 46% ) !important;
}   
.main-navigation ul {
    background: #003559 !important;
}   
.main-navigation a:hover {
    /*color: #767676;*/
    color: hsl( 250, 50%, 46% ) !important;
}   

.menu-toggle {
    color: #fff !important;
}


.single-featured-image-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #003559 !important;
}
```

Comment: its probably a css issue, can you post your css?

Comment: Sure. Please find it attached. I've tried to completely remove it, but no effect.